# How can I get the row of data for each Policy where the RecentChat has happened between the StartTerm and EndTerm?

Tags: sql

My data looks like this

```
**Policy  RecentContact  StartTerm   EndTerm**     
Pol234    12/08/2020       05/06/2020  07/09/2020 

Pol234    12/08/2020       01/01/2021  08/08/2021 
Pol234    12/08/2020       01/01/2020  04/06/2020
Pol567    15/01/2021       15/01/2021  01/12/2021
Pol567    15/01/2021       14/01/2020  14/01/2021
```

I have multiple rows of data where Policy and RecentContact are the same however the StartTerm and EndTerm are different. How can I get the row of data for each Policy where the RecentChat has happened between the StartTerm and EndTerm?
So for Pol234 I'd want to only pull row 1 and for Pol567 I'd want to pull row 4

Comment: Can you some more rows with sample data, and also specify the expected result?

Comment: I've some more, does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use `between`:

```
select t.*
from t
where RecentContact between starttem and endterm;
```

This assumes that the three columns are stored as `date`s and not strings.  If they are strings, fix the data model!